# CSS Transitions - understand functionality

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, transition

I recently implemented [Anno.js](http://iamdanfox.github.io/anno.js/) to my project. For styling purposes, I redesigned the "Anno Boxes" to use bootstrap modal layout.
This is what the AnnoBox normally looks like:

```
this._annoElem = $("<div class='anno anno-hidden " + this.className + "'>\n<div class='anno-inner'>  <div class='anno-arrow'></div>  </div>\n</div>");
        this._annoElem.find('.anno-inner').append(this.contentElem()).append(this.buttonsElem());
```

And I just removed all anno classes and inserted the appropriate bootstrap classes for modal, so `modal, modal dialog, modal-content, modal-hedaer`) and stlying is fine, but there is one problem. Anno uses some transitions for the change of two boxes (see `anno2.show`) on Anno page. And after I removed those anno classes (causing the transitions) I have sth. like delays in between the time the boxes appear, because there is no transition any more. Now I'm wondering how I can implement the transition functionality to my modals as well.

For me it seems, that the transitions come from the classes `anno` and `anno-hidden`, which are defined the following:

```
.anno {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 5000;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: default;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, margin;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity, margin;
  transition-property: opacity, margin;
}

.anno.anno-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.anno-overlay.anno-hidden {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

You can also find the complete css at [Annos Github](https://github.com/iamdanfox/anno.js/blob/gh-pages/dist/anno.css) and [here](https://github.com/iamdanfox/anno.js/blob/gh-pages/dist/anno.js) the complete js.

I tried to add the code written in class Anno to my modal class as well, so I added

```
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.265, 1);
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, margin;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity, margin;

  transition-property: opacity, margin;
```

But this changes nothing. I'm not sure how this works, and how this all works together, so somehow it seems like it works with changing the opacity first from 100% to 0% (to fade out the first box) and then (on the other box) from 0% to 100%. But I have no idea so far how I can also get to this behaviour. Can somebody explain me, how this works exactly and how I could implement this?